# Multiple Image onloads with Javascript

Tags: javascript, onload

I am trying to figure out a way to run two image onload events. The current code I have below only calls the first onload event and ignores the second. Is it possible to run both onload events synchronously in one document? Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadImage()
{
//do stuff
}
</script>

<img src="http://www.example.com/image.gif" onload="loadImage()" />

<img src="http://www.example.com/2image.gif" onload="loadImage()" />
```

Comment: What is the issue and how do you know which event is being fired and which is not?  Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle because onload events are fired reliably for images?

Comment: @jfriend00 - (potentially) Interesting result: http://jsfiddle.net/KfWcq/

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I see loadImage getting called twice when I run your jsFiddle in Firefox and Chrome.  Did you see a problem?

Comment: @jfriend00 - No, none at all. `:)`

Comment: Hmmm, if I try a simple document.write it only prints out once. I'm not sure why it shows it being called twice.

Comment: @alan: Each call to `document.write` will clear the content of the page first. So if you call it twice, you will only see the content of the second call.